# In SQL can you GRANT privileges to MULTIPLE accounts with a single command?

Tags: sql, sql-grant, accounts

This is just for a uni assignment. Instead of doing this:

```
DENY DELETE ON SECRETAGENT, SECRETMISSION, AGENTMISSION TO A1;

DENY DELETE ON SECRETAGENT, SECRETMISSION, AGENTMISSION TO A2;

DENY DELETE ON SECRETAGENT, SECRETMISSION, AGENTMISSION TO A3;
```

is it possible to just write one line like this?

```
DENY DELETE ON SECRETAGENT, SECRETMISSION, AGENTMISSION TO A1, A2, A3;
```

I haven't found any site that specifies whether this can or cannot be done.

Comment: I think [you can do it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) but you have to fix the way you specify users. look at the examples

Comment: okay thanks, I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/revoke.html):

```
REVOKE
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    FROM user [, user] ...

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION
    FROM user [, user] ...
```

The `[]` mean, it's optional, so yes, you can do it in one line for multiple users, but not for multiple **named** objects (, but for multiple objects with wildcards, like `ON databasename.*`).

Comment: thanks! but what do mean not for multiple named objects? so I can't have it for all three tables on the same line?

Comment: Well, you could have a try, but if it were possible, there would be `ON [object_type] priv_level [, ON [object_type] priv_level]`. You see what I mean?

Comment: You tagged the question with MySQL. There is no `deny` in MySQL. `revoke` is the equivalent.

Comment: SQL is just the language with which you're querying your database. Is it SQL Server? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The question says "Produce the SQL statements for the following scenarios:". The lecture notes we did just say "Permissions in SQL" nothing more specific.

Comment: MySQL is a widely used database management system. So I consider this question correctly answered. In SQL Server there's the `DENY` command (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188338.aspx), but it seems to be the same as `revoke` in MySQL.